# Network switch stops working until power cycled, but replacing the switch and the router changes nothing

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch

My home network setup is:

```
Modem---Router---Wireless device
               |-Wireless device
               |-...
               \-Unmanaged network switch---Wired device
                                          |-Wired device
                                          |-Mesh point---Wireless device
                                                       |-Wireless device
                                                       \-...
```

This setup **usually works fine**, but occasionally the network switch stops working, although it clearly still has power. **Power-cycling the switch fixes the issue** within seconds, so I initially thought the issue is with the switch, **but replacing the switch with another unit from a different manufacturer results in identical behavior** which makes me suspect the problem lies elsewhere.

This used to have occurred infrequently, but has been getting worse recently, and now even power-cycling everything only fixes the problem for a few seconds.

Where is the fault likely to lie?

**Update:** I had another router of the same model as my existing router, so I've swapped the two to ensure this isn't something that suddenly got bad with the router... but nothing has changed.

Comment: Try putting it on a UPS. when I was young, i tried diagnose a PC in a trailer home far from any city. Seems this was the third PC they had had in a year. something about the power it was receiving would put it into a failing state. I'm not an electrical engineer, so cant really say exactly what was going on, but moving the PC from the kitchen to the living room (using a different AC outlet) fixed the issue, but I did have to wait a few hours for the capacitors to discharge (I guess), before it would come back to life.

Comment: @FrankThomas interesting! For starters, I'm going to try and connect the switch to a different outlet to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Probably not important, but is the Mesh point connected via LAN (cable)? Then, if I'm not mistaken, it should be either a regular AP or a Mesh Portal.

Comment: @Albin It was set up as a mesh point, then connected via LAN to the router. It has been working well for a while, though, before the issues started - which is why I don't think it was set up incorrectly.

Comment: I wouldn't say so necessarily (e.g. if mesh point is connected via LAN and to WLAN after a while, you would have a loop), what happens if you disconnect almost all devices from the network using for example this config: modem <-> router <-> switch <-> wired device?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information yet to identify the problem. So right now I would try to eliminate as many potential problems as possible to narrow down the actual problem. E.g. just use the switch with two devices. If the error persists add full information on the "small configuration" to your question: diagram including the settings like IP, MAC etc. basically everything relevant up to layer 3 (with a switch layer 1+2 should be enough but just in case...). That might give us more hints.

A shot in the dark: It might be a loop caused by your mesh point if it's connected via LAN and WLAN (switch shut down after a few seconds with different routers sounds like it). Disconnect the mesh point and see if it helps.

Comment: I think that's a great advice, thanks! I'll try to minimize the network then add one device at a time and wait to see how it behaves. And I'll add the mesh point last.